# My lonovo thinkbook 15 fingerprint not work and not exsist setting options

Tags: 22.04, lenovo

I bought a Lenovo Thinkbook laptop, the problem I have is that the fingerprint settings are not activated for me, and I don't know where the problem comes from.

I am sending the output of a series of commands. Thank you for your help.

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0489:e0cd Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 24ae:2013 Shenzhen Rapoo Technology Co., Ltd. Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:212b Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`

```
[sudo] password for hossein: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libpam-fprintd is already the newest version (1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libapache2-mod-php8.1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 325 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libpam-fprintd is already the newest version (1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libapache2-mod-php8.1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 325 not upgraded.
```

`sudo pam-auth-update`
[image]

Users setting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this fingerprint device is not yet supported. There's a [list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/Lenovo) on the Arch Wiki of Lenovo devices, and it highlights those with a non-functional fingerprint reader. Your device (USB ID `04f3:0c4b` is on the list highlighted in red).

On the good side the upstream libfprint developers have an open [merge request](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/merge_requests/356) which hopes to enable this device. Sadly it's not yet working.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to compile Ubuntu and add this merge request to it?

Comment: It may be possible to build a test deb and install that, for sure. But from the comments on the merge request it doesn't work reliably enough as it is, so not a lot of point right now.